# File Not Found : maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

i am trying to compile schema from an artifact(dependency) using jaxb2 plugin , i followed the topic: Compiling a schema from a Maven artifact in

http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-UsingcustomJAXB2plugins

and the code i have is

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                    <generatePackage>com.xxx.it.esp.subscription.schema</generatePackage>
                    <generateDirectory>src/main/java/</generateDirectory>
                    <!-- 
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <dependencyResource>
                                <groupId>com.xxx.it.esp</groupId>
                                <artifactId>esp-schemas</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                <resource>index.xsd</resource>
                            </dependencyResource>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry index.xsd not found in the jar esp-schemas-1.0-SNAPSHOT

By the way index.xsd is under src/main/resources/schema/ folder and i tried giving the entire folder also but same error

Answer (score 1):

Please try `<resource>schema/index.xsd</resource>`. The `resource` is the path of XSD inside the JAR.